# Magento : Create Layered Navigation API to Show Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, layered-navigation, rest-api

[image]

I want to fetch these attributes of layered navigation using REST API.

Provide me suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I Know it is a late reply but it may help some other magento api developers.

```
protected function _create($data){
    $typeid = $data['categoryId'];
    $userid = $data['userId'];
    $pagesize = $data['limit'];
    $pageno = $data['page'];
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();


try
{


        $layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($typeid);
        Mage::register('current_category', $category);
        Mage::register('current_entity_key', $category->getPath());
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
        $products = $layer->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        if($pageno==1){
            $filter=array();
            $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();
            $min_price = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
            $max_price = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();
            $price['minPrice']=$min_price;
            $price['maxPrice']=$max_price;
            $json['priceRange']=$price;
            $json['priceRangeApplied']=$price;
            $json['attributes'] = array();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
                    $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
                } elseif ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
                    $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_decimal';
                } else {
                    $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
                }

                $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();

                if(array_key_exists($attribute->getAttributeCode(),$data['filters'])){
                foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
                    if(in_array($option->getValue(),explode(',',$data['filters'][$attribute->getAttributeCode()]))){
                        $count[] = array('optionId' => $option->getValue(), 'optionLabel' => $option->getLabel(),'selected'=>true);
                    }else {
                        $count[] = array('optionId' => $option->getValue(), 'optionLabel' => $option->getLabel(),'selected'=>false);
                    }
                }
                }else{
                    foreach($result->getItems() as $option) {
                        $count[] = array('optionId' => $option->getValue(),'optionLabel' => $option->getLabel(),'selected'=>false);
                    }
                }
                if(count($count)>=1){
                    $json['attributes'][] = array('attributeCode'=>$attribute->getAttributeCode(),'attributeLabel'=>ucfirst($attribute->getFrontend_label()),'attributeValues'=>$count);
                }
                unset($count);
            }
        }
        $minprice=0;
        $maxprice=0;
        if(array_key_exists('filters',$data)){
            foreach ($data['filters'] as $key=>$item) {
                $itemss=array();
                if($key=='price'){
                    $priceRanges =explode(',',$item);
                    foreach($priceRanges as $priceRange) {
                        $pricelimit = explode('-',$priceRange);
                        $minprice = $pricelimit[0];
                        $maxprice = $pricelimit[1];

                    }

                }
                else{
                    $itemss=explode(',',$item);
                    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $key);
                    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
                    $tableAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_idx';

                    $conditions = array(
                        "{$tableAlias}.entity_id = e.entity_id",
                        $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.attribute_id = ?",
                            $attribute->getAttributeId()),
                        $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.store_id = ?", 1),
                        $connection->quoteInto("{$tableAlias}.value IN (?)", $itemss)
                    );

                    $products->getSelect()->join(
                        array($tableAlias =>  Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/layer_filter_attribute')->getMainTable()),
                        implode(' AND ', $conditions),
                        array()
                    );
                }

            }
            $products->addFinalPrice();
            if($minprice!=0&&$maxprice!=0) {
                $products->getSelect()
                    ->where('price_index.final_price <= ' . $maxprice)->where('price_index.final_price >= ' . $minprice);
                $price['minPrice']=(int)$minprice;
                $price['maxPrice']=(int)$maxprice;
                $json['priceRangeApplied']=$price;
            }
        }
        $totalproducts=$products->getSize();
        if($pagesize&&$pageno){
            $products->setPageSize($pagesize)
                ->setCurPage($pageno);
        }
        $i=0;
        $flag=0;
        $response = array();

        foreach($products as $result3){
            $response[$i] = array('productId'=>$result3->getId(),'productName'=>$result3->getName(),'productPrice'=>$result3->getPrice());//give what ever values you need.
            $i++;
        }

        $bestprodts = $response;
        $noofpages = $totalproducts/$pagesize;



    $result                              =   array();
    $result['status']                    =   1;
    if(!$totalproducts){
        if($min_price==0&&$max_price==0){
            $result['message']='No products available in this category.';
        }else{
            $result['message']='No products found. Please check the filter.';
        }

    }else{
    $result['message']='Success';
    }
    $result['noofpages']=ceil($noofpages);
    $result['totalProducts']=$totalproducts;
    $result['data']['productList']=$bestprodts;
    if($pageno==1){
        $result['data']['filters']=$json;
    }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $result           =   array();
    $result['status'] = 2;
    $result['message'] = "Product Listing failed";
}

echo json_encode($result);
return json_encode($result);
```

}

Request Format {
"categoryId":"",
"limit":"",
"page":"",
"filters":{
"price":"from-to",
"attribute_code":"values "
}
}